# Image doesn't center on large screens

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to center the image in my website below the navigation. It centers correctly on smaller screens in all browsers however, On larger screens it doesn't center in any browsers. I have tried encasing the image with a 'p' tag and using text-align to center it, but it didn't work. I have consulted others who are more knowledgeable in html and css and they have found nothing. I have searched the internet for an issue similar to my own have found nothing. Any insights into this problem would be appreciated.

UPDATE: The problem has been fixed thanks to the people here. I didn't expect the multitude of quick and helpful responses. Thank you.

Here is my HTML and CSS.

```css
html{
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html>a{
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.header{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;/*#00FF00*/
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  z-index: -100;
  font-size:2em;
}
.header>h1{
  position:relative;
  float:right;
}
.titlehead{
  color: white;
}
.logo{
  z-index: 1;
  float:left;
}
.navBar{
  position:relative;
  top:15%;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.nav{
 color:black;
}
.nav>ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  height:100%;
}
.nav>ul>li{
  text-decoration:none;
  float:left;
}
.nav>ul>li:hover{
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
   -moz-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
     -o-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
        transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625); /* custom */
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:4px;
    border-bottom-color:black;;
}
.nav>ul>li>a{
  list-style-type:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:15px;
  font-size:1.7em;
  color: black;
}
.images{
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 top:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
.images>img{
 display:block;
 width:500px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
.images>p{
 display:block;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 text-align:center;
}
#melita{
 position: relative;
 top: -15%;
 transform: translateY(15%);
 width:100%;
}
.wrapper{
 /*-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
}
.content{
 /*position:relative;
 top:50%;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
      <title> PopcornDotOrg</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <meta name=viewport content='width=815'>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
   <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="header">
                <div class="titlehead">
                  <a href="index.php"><img class="logo" src="logoScaled.png" alt="logo"/></a>
                  <h1>PopcornDotOrg</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navBar">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Recent</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                    <li><a href="archive.php">Archive</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
  <div class="images">
   <!--<h2>These muffins are terrible</h2>-->
   <p><img alt="logo" src="logo.png"/></p>
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `float: left` and `width: 50%` in your `.navBar` are the reasons that caused the issue. Try remove `float:left` would work.

Also, try removing `>` from the follow css class, because your `img` tag is not directly nested in the `div` with css class `.images`

```
.images img {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here is the working version.

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  /*#00FF00*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -100;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.header>h1 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.titlehead {
  color: white;
}
.logo {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}
.navBar {
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
  color: black;
}
.nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav>ul>li {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
.nav>ul>li:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  -moz-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  -o-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  /* custom */
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  ;
}
.nav>ul>li>a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: black;
}
.images {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.images img {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.images >p {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#melita {
  position: relative;
  top: -15%;
  transform: translateY(15%);
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  /*-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
}
.content {
  /*position:relative;
 top:50%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="titlehead">
      <a href="index.php">
        <img class="logo" src="logoScaled.png" alt="logo" />
      </a>
      <h1>PopcornDotOrg</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navBar">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Recent</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Popular</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="archive.php">Archive</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <!--<h2>These muffins are terrible</h2>-->
    <p>
      <img alt="logo" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com/help/images/photo_border.png" />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An image is not center because `.navBar` has `float` attribute;

Add one new class called `.clear-fix`, then add one more div after `.navBar`:

```
.clear-fix {
  clear: both;
}
```

HTML code:

Check result online here: https://jsfiddle.net/1q0o88eh/2/

```
<div class="navBar"></div>
<div class="clear-fix"></div> <---- New here
```

Comment: I apologize for my lack of clarity in the asking of this question. I did not mean the image in header. I was asking about the image in the body of the page, below the navigation. I will modify my post to clarify. Even so, your answer did center the logo at the top of the page, just not the one I was having trouble with.

Comment: @Awkwardtaco: Could you add a real image url for this, it's easy to check issue then just link to your local `src="logo.png"`.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM:**

The problem lies in the way you are styling your navbar, you are using `float: left;` and `width: 50%;`, so when both the image and the navbar fit in the x-axis they will diplay next to each other. That's why this happens on larger screens, the viewport is big enough for both to fit.

---

**SOLUTION:**

Replace:

```
.navBar{
  position:relative;
  top:15%;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

With:

```
.navBar{
  position:relative;
  top:15%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mkpwah7/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  /*#00FF00*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -100;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.header>h1 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.titlehead {
  color: white;
}
.logo {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}
.navBar {
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
  color: black;
}
.nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav>ul>li {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
.nav>ul>li:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  -moz-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  -o-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
  /* custom */
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  ;
}
.nav>ul>li>a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: black;
}
.images {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.images>img {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#melita {
  position: relative;
  top: -15%;
  transform: translateY(15%);
}
.wrapper {
  /*-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
}
.content {
  /*position:relative;
 top:50%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="titlehead">
      <a href="index.php">
        <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/74x74" alt="logo" />
      </a>
      <h1>PopcornDotOrg</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navBar">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Recent</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Popular</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="archive.php">Archive</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <!--<h2>These muffins are terrible</h2>-->
    <img alt="logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1q0o88eh/3/)

```css
.clear-fix{
  clear: both;
}    
html{
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html>a{
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.header{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;/*#00FF00*/
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  z-index: -100;
  font-size:2em;
}
.header>h1{
  position:relative;
  float:right;
}
.titlehead{
  color: white;
}
.logo{
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}
.navBar{
  position:relative;
  top:15%;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.nav{
 color:black;
}
.nav>ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  height:100%;
}
.nav>ul>li{
  text-decoration:none;
  float:left;
}
.nav>ul>li:hover{
 -webkit-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
   -moz-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
     -o-transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625);
        transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.380, 0.410, 0.605, 0.625); /* custom */
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:4px;
    border-bottom-color:black;;
}
.nav>ul>li>a{
  list-style-type:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:15px;
  font-size:1.7em;
  color: black;
}
#melita{
 position: relative;
 top: -15%;
 transform: translateY(15%);
 width:100%;
}
.wrapper{
 /*-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
}
.content{
 /*position:relative;
 top:50%;*/
}




.images{
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
}
.images>img{
 display:block;
 width:500px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
          <div class="header">
                <div class="titlehead">
                  <a href="index.php"><img class="logo" src="logoScaled.png" alt="logo"/></a>
                  <h1>PopcornDotOrg</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navBar">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Recent</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                    <li><a href="archive.php">Archive</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-fix"></div>
  <div class="images">
   <!--<h2>These muffins are terrible</h2>-->
   <img alt="logo" src="http://videohoconline.edu.vn/upload/images/video-day-seo-online_thumb.jpg"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```